# Reducing characters in a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have a database table, am using mysql as below

```
study_id lab_no date_rec
MTA2-001 EPI800001 2015-03-05
MTA1-001 EPI800002 2015-03-05
MTA3-002 EPI800003 2015-03-05
```

i need to reduce the lab_no from EPI800001 to EPI8001.
How do i do it??
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

If you want to store new values in db (update) do:

```
UPDATE table_name SET lab_no = REPLACE(lab_no, '0000', '00');
```

If you just want to select them in the new format use:

```
SELECT REPLACE(lab_no, '0000', '00') as lab_no FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select REPLACE(lab_no,'0000','00')
```

Also do note that if you want to make a permanent change in your data then only use the UPDATE query else you can use the select query to get the manipulated result.

Answer (score 1):

Can also use `SUBSTRING` method.

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(lab_no,1,6),SUBSTRING(lab_no,8,9));
```